# HashSet that preserves ordering

Tags: c#, .net, hashset

I need a HashSet that preserves insertion ordering, are there any implementations of this in the framework?

Comment: I imagine you mean like Java's [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Comment: yeah the simplest thing to do is to wrap a linked list and hashset together ... its what I ended up doing in the past. useful for an LRU implementation

Comment: By definition of Set should not preserve any order.

Comment: @vash In lieu of that remark, the question should then really be "I need a data structure that preserved insertion order and that has access characteristics of a hashset, ie. O(1) etc."

Comment: So what you actually want is a List that prevents duplicates, right? Cause that's really the only reason to use a HashSet instead of a list or array. In which case you could easily implement a class that contained both a list and a HashSet and checked against/maintained the HashSet during add/remove.

Answer (score 48):

**Standard .NET `HashSet` do not preserve the insertion order.**
For simple tests the insertion order may be preserved due to an accident, but it's not guaranteed and would not always work that way. To prove that it is enough to do some removals in between.

See this question for more information on that: [Does HashSet preserve insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657263/does-hashset-preserve-insertion-order?rq=1)

I have briefly implemented a `HashSet` which guarantees insertion order. It uses the `Dictionary` to look up items and the `LinkedList` to preserve order. All three insertion, removal and lookup work still in O(1).

```
public class OrderedSet<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<T, LinkedListNode<T>> m_Dictionary;
    private readonly LinkedList<T> m_LinkedList;

    public OrderedSet()
        : this(EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public OrderedSet(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        m_Dictionary = new Dictionary<T, LinkedListNode<T>>(comparer);
        m_LinkedList = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public int Count => m_Dictionary.Count;

    public virtual bool IsReadOnly => m_Dictionary.IsReadOnly;

    void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
    {
        Add(item);
    }

    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        if (m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(item)) return false;
        var node = m_LinkedList.AddLast(item);
        m_Dictionary.Add(item, node);
        return true;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        m_LinkedList.Clear();
        m_Dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        if (item == null) return false;
        var found = m_Dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out var node);
        if (!found) return false;
        m_Dictionary.Remove(item);
        m_LinkedList.Remove(node);
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_LinkedList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return item != null && m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        m_LinkedList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really provide an overload taking an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to pass to the same overload of `IDictionary<T>`. Out of the box, your example check equality through object references (for classes, at least) and offers no options to change that behaviour. I understand however that this is a simple example.

Comment: @SimonBelanger Agree. I have just posted a version which implements all variants of common constructors and methods here:  http://gmamaladze.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/hashset-that-preserves-insertion-order-or-net-implementation-of-linkedhashset/

Comment: Isn´t `m_LinkedList.Remove(node);` actually O(n)?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - Good question. Well yes, but actually no. If you want to delete a specific element, because you have to find the element, the removal itself is O(1). If you take a look at my implementation we use a dictionary to find it which is O(1), instead of interesting the list. first.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987542/time-complexity-of-deletion-in-a-linked-list

Comment: @HimBromBeere: It's `O(1)` in particular because @GeorgeMamaladze is storing the `LinkedListNode<T>` reference, which makes removal in a doubly-linked list constant time.

Comment: Why not just use a Dictionary<T, int> and a list <T> ? The dictionary essentially acts like a hash if you check for contains on insertion and list keeps the order, the dictionary keeps track of indices on insertion.

Answer (score 23):

You can get this functionality easily using [`KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx) specifying the same type argument for TKey and TItem:

```
public class OrderedHashSet<T> : KeyedCollection<T, T>
{
    protected override T GetKeyForItem(T item)
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you call `Remove` will it call [`Remove(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Remove(TKey)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132459(v=vs.110).aspx)? The first is O(n) and the second is O(1).

Comment: It calls `Remove(TKey)` because it is the one on the most derived class.  However, calling Remove() when the collection is cast as a Collection<T> or ICollection<T> will call the `Remove(T)` overload.

Comment: Another clarification: Both `Remove(T)` and `Remove(TKey)` are O(n) because `KeyedCollection<T, T>` uses a list to store the items.

Comment: Note that unlike a regular `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>`, this will throw a `System.ArgumentException` on duplicate key instead of returning `false`.

Comment: @kcnygaard - why do you believe that KeyedCollection maintains insertion ordering? Internally it is simply a Dictionary, which is [known to not maintain order under all conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694344/199364).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: `KeyedCollection<TKey, TIitem>` derives from `Collection<TItem>`, which implements `IList<TItem>`, i.e., indexed access.
It is fundamentally a _list_ that _also_ provides key-based access (by default via an aux. internal dictionary).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: From the [docs for the `.Remove(TKey key)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2.remove): "This method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count." It seems that the internally used dictionary is only used for key-based lookups that return the associated item directly, it doesn't also store information about that item's index in the internal list.

Comment: [OrderedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-6.0) offers the same results as this solution without the additional implementation.

Answer (score 14):

If you need constant complexity of `Add`, `Remove`, `Contains` and order preservation, then there's no such collection in .NET Framework 4.5.

If you're okay with 3rd party code, take a look at my repository (permissive MIT license):
https://github.com/OndrejPetrzilka/Rock.Collections

There's `OrderedHashSet<T>` collection:

- based on classic `HashSet<T>` source code (from .NET Core)
- preserves **order of insertions** and allows **manual reordering**
- features **reversed enumeration**
- has **same operation complexities** as `HashSet<T>`
- `Add` and `Remove` operations are 20% slower compared to `HashSet<T>`
- consumes 8 more bytes of memory per item

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OrderedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-6.0) to preserve the order of insertion. But beware of the cost of Removing items (O(n)).