# HashTable to Dictionary conversion

Tags: c#

I have converted a hashtable into dictionary. but the problem is when I go to print the values it does not show in sequencing order.

```
aHashtable.Add(1014, "201");
aHashtable.Add(10, "ATIB");
aHashtable.Add(143, "LOVE");
aHashtable.Add(111, "HATE");

var dict= aHashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);

foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> keyValuePair in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key + ": " +keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: did any of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test this code :

```
var aHashtable = new Hashtable {{1014, "201"}, {10, "ATIB"}, {143, "LOVE"}, {111, "HATE"}};
var dict = aHashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry> ().ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value).OrderBy(x=>x.Key);

foreach (var keyValuePair in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key + ": " + keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

Comment: if you need to order by name,only just replace .OrderBy(x=>x.Name) by .OrderBy(x=>x.Key)

Answer (score 5):

By default a dictionary is not sorted. C# has a [OrderedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) though.

See also: [The order of elements in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007782/the-order-of-elements-in-dictionary)

Comment: I would recommend to use a generic `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` which is easier to convert from a `Dictionary` and avoid boxing when use

Comment: Depends what the OP wants. SortedDict sorts based on keys. That's different than what OrderedDictionary does.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries don't store values based on order of entry.

From docs:

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

You need an [ordered dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694182/ordereddictionary-and-dictionary).