# How to iterate in reverse through an OrderedDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, ordereddictionary

How can I iterate through an [OrderedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) in reverse and access its keys?

Since it doesn't have any support for LINQ extensions, I have tried the following:

```
var orderedDictionary= new OrderedDictionary();
orderedDictionary.Add("something", someObject);
orderedDictionary.Add("another", anotherObject);

for (var dictIndex = orderedDictionary.Count - 1; dictIndex != 0; dictIndex--)
{
    // It gives me the value, but how do I get the key?
    // E.g., "something" and "another".
    var key = orderedDictionary[dictIndex];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you iterate it in reverse or normal order because as documentations states, *The elements of an OrderedDictionary are not sorted by the key, unlike the elements of a SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> class.*

Comment: The insertion order is the reason why I'm using OrderDictionary, I need to iterate it accordingly (in reverse).

Comment: You can always iterate through the keys property of a dictionary.

Comment: @jdweng but I need to iterate the dictionary according to the insertion order, in reverse. During that iteration I need to pick the keys to do other operations.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately the class is overencapsulated. The [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/ordereddictionary.cs,c5cedabdfd3ba6b2,references) of the indexer is like this `return ((DictionaryEntry)objectsArray[index]).Value;` and you need a method like this `return ((DictionaryEntry)objectsArray[index]);` which does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lessen the complexity of this problem significantly by using a regular `Dictionary` (or `SortedDictionary`, depending on your requirements) and keep a secondary `List` to keep track of the keys' insertion order. You can even use a class to facilitate this organization:

```
public class DictionaryList<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dict;
    private List<TKey> _list;

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return _dict[key]; }
        set { _dict[key] = value; }
    }

    public DictionaryList()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        _list = new List<TKey>();
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _dict.Add(key, value);
        _list.Add(key);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TValue> GetValuesReverse()
    {
        for (int i = _list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            yield return _dict[_list[i]];
    }
}
```

*(And of course add whatever other methods you need as well.)*

Comment: this achieves what I'm aiming for and will have less restrictions for further customizations.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest to use `SortedDictionary<K, V>`? It does support LINQ and it is type safe:

```
var orderedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
orderedDictionary.Add("something", "a");
orderedDictionary.Add("another", "b");

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in orderedDictionary.Reverse())
{
}
```

Also, as Ivan Stoev pointed out in a comment, the returned items of the `OrderedDictionary` aren't ordered at all, so `SortedDictionary` is what you want.

Comment: I need to keep the insertion order intact, if I'm not mistaken, SortedDictionary won't keep the insertion order.

Comment: Then use a `Dictionary<K, V>`

Comment: I don't believe a Dictionary keeps the insertion order as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694182/ordereddictionary-and-dictionary

Comment: If the order is that important, why not make it the key?

Comment: I want to use the dictionary for fast lookups based on a string key. The dictionary serves 2 purposes, being able to iterate it in regards its insertion order and on a different process to do fast lookups.

Comment: Personally I would separate that in two: a list and a dictionary. The other option of casting can get very expensive when you iterate over it a lot or when you have a lot of items.

Comment: Yeah, this problem's complexity would be greatly lessened if alongside the dictionary you also kept a list of keys as you add them. You could even create a custom class to facilitate this for you.

Comment: FWIW, a list of keys is just as expensive as a list of items.

Comment: This should work : sDict.Keys.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x).Select(x => sDict[x])

Comment: It works but it is very expensive on the performance. @jdweng

Comment: @PatrickHofman *Personally I would separate that in two: a list and a dictionary.* This is exactly what the class in question does internally - keeping `ArrayList` and `HashTable` :) MS didn't create a generic version of it, but it's quite easy to roll your own, which I would do if I needed it w/o any over encapsulation or restrictions - there was absolutely no problem to expose what OP wants, not counting the fact that `Keys` and `Values` could have indexers as well.

Comment: Any linq method is expensive since it will iterate through all the keys.  A simple FOR loop is better since you can break out of loop when you find a match instead of  checking every key.

Answer (score 2):

> Since it doesn't have any support for LINQ extensions...

That's because it's a non-generic `Enumerable`. You can make it generic by casting it to the right type:

```
foreach (var entry in orderedDictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Reverse()) {
    var key = entry.Key;
    var value = entry.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get an element at an index like this:

```
orderedDictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(dictIndex);
```

And for getting the `Key`:

```
orderedDictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(dictIndex).K‌​ey.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try, sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Beware the O(n) complexity of `ElementAt`. Applying this to each element in the collection will therefore give o(n2) complexity (which is probably going to be quite nasty if used in the wrong place)

Comment: @spender wasn't aware of that fact. thank you for bringing it up.

Comment: Since you're using `Cast<DictionaryEntry>()`, it becomes an `IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry>`, so you can use linq and foreach. No need for ElementAt()

Answer (score 1):

I am not bothered with the order fact. You can get the key by copying the keys to an indexable collection. Also the condition of the loop needed to be changed to `dictIndex > -1;`.

Please try this:

```
var orderedDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();
orderedDictionary.Add("something", someObject);
orderedDictionary.Add("another", anotherObject);

object[] keys = new object[orderedDictionary.Keys.Count];
orderedDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

for (var dictIndex = orderedDictionary.Count-1; dictIndex > -1; dictIndex--)
{
    // It gives me the value, but how do I get the key?
    // E.g., "something" and "another".
    var key = orderedDictionary[dictIndex];

    // Get your key, e.g. "something" and "another"
    var key = keys[dictIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use an OrderdDictionary, you can always use a SortedDictionary like below.

```
var orderedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

orderedDictionary.Add(1, "Abacas");
orderedDictionary.Add(2, "Lion");
orderedDictionary.Add(3, "Zebera");

var reverseList = orderedDictionary.ToList().OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value);

foreach (var item in reverseList)
{
    Debug.Print(item.Value);
}
```