# Generic dictionary that can retain the order of keys by the way they were added

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Dictionary dict = Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dict.Add("someKey1", new List<string>());
dict.Add("orange", new List<string>());
dict.Add("foo", new List<string>());
```

And then when I iterate over the keys, I'd like them to have retained the order as they were added:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in myDictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
}
```

Should print out:

```
someKey1
orange
foo
```

I know that c# Dictionary keys don't retain their order as they were added, so is there another way I can do this so that the keys retain their order?

Comment: Queue<T> class is worth a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694182/ordereddictionary-and-dictionary

Answer (score 2):

A generic ordered dictionary does not exist in .NET, but you could use the `OrderedDictionary` class instead. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: This is not generic. I need a way to keep the keys ordered as they were added and also be able to create values of type List<string>.

Comment: Yes I did read, there is no generic way, only the `OrderedDictionary`. Else you have to implement it on your own or use thrid party classes

Answer (score -1):

Use `Queue` class from `System.Collections.Generic` to ensure the order.

```
// Create queue
Queue<TestItem> queue = new Queue<TestItem>();
// Add item
queue.Enqueue(new TestItem { });
// Fetch item
queue.Dequeue();
```