# DictionaryEntry seems obsolete, but how is OrderedDictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value, deprecated, ordereddictionary

`System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` is avoided for new projects, as seen in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionaryentry?view=net-6.0):

> We don't recommend that you use the DictionaryEntry structure for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use a generic KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> structure along with the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> class. For more information, see Non-generic collections shouldn't be used on GitHub.

However the `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`, which is not marked on its [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-6.0) page as deprecated, cannot be used with `KeyValuePair`s and it is required to bring the `DictionaryEntry`s for value access.

```cs
var pages = new OrderedDictionary()
{
    { "Index", "Home" },
    { "Policies", "Privacy Policy" },
    // ...
};

foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pages)
{
    // OK
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in pages)
{
    // InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' 
    //     to type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]'.
}
```

Given these, should we now consider `OrderedDictionary` as obsolete as `DictionaryEntry`? Or is it still OK to use?

---

**Edit:**

I am not talking about the difference of `Dictionary<>` and `OrderedDictionary`. What I want is choosing `KeyValuePair` instead of `DictionaryEntry` because the latter one is not recommended any more, but I could not find a generic version of `OrderedDictionary`, like `Dictionary<>` for [`Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OrderedDictionary and Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694182/ordereddictionary-and-dictionary)

Comment: @Jazb Not quite, because the suggested question is about the difference of two classes, but mine is about how to use (or whether to avoid) a class with an obsolete component when its up-to-date counterpart is not accepted.

Comment: Note that it is a *recommendation*, not obsoletion, which can be marked with the `ObsoleteAttribute` but that hasn't been done here. If you truly need an `OrderedDictionary` then you have no choice but to use it. There isn't a generic variant of `OrderedDictionary`.

Comment: You can use SortedDictionary or SortedList, if you really need access an ordered collection by index, you can create one with List+Dictionary in two ticks.

Comment: Forget xxxDictionary - what do you want to do?