# Any existing .Net Ordered Set?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, set

I'm looking for .Net class, which will basically:

- Ensure that items are unique in it(like an HashSet)
- Ensure that when we enumerate, we get items in the same order than we inserted them(Like a List)

Is there an existing .Net class that does this?

I'm aware of the `HashSet`(which doesn't guarantee the order), the `SortedSet`(which order on the content), but they don't match my need. I don't have any other needs(like a `Stack` or a `Queue`).

My current alternative is to have a `List<>` and use the `Contains(...)` before Adding and Removing data.

Comment: Hvae you tried `Dictionary`, particulary at `SortedDictionary`? It would kind of a hack, but will fulfill your needs

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Yes but I don't really have any key to specify(and I'm not sure that a `Dictionary` guarantee any order on enumeration.

Comment: you will insert keys (that will be your values from the list) and value can be anything random. Oh, I mean not `SortedDictionary` but `OrderedDictionary`

Answer (score 5):

You are right. HashSet do not preserve the insertion order.

[Stackoverflow: HashSet that preserves ordering by achitaka-san](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853085/1153464)
It uses the Dictionary to look up items and the LinkedList to preserve order. All three insertion, removal and lookup work still in O(1).

```
public class OrderedSet<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<T, LinkedListNode<T>> m_Dictionary;
    private readonly LinkedList<T> m_LinkedList;

    public OrderedSet()
        : this(EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public OrderedSet(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        m_Dictionary = new Dictionary<T, LinkedListNode<T>>(comparer);
        m_LinkedList = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return m_Dictionary.Count; }
    }

    public virtual bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return m_Dictionary.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
    {
        Add(item);
    }

    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        if (m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(item)) return false;
        LinkedListNode<T> node = m_LinkedList.AddLast(item);
        m_Dictionary.Add(item, node);
        return true;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        m_LinkedList.Clear();
        m_Dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> node;
        bool found = m_Dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out node);
        if (!found) return false;
        m_Dictionary.Remove(item);
        m_LinkedList.Remove(node);
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_LinkedList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        m_LinkedList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }
}
```

Another implementation:

[@Codeproject: HashSet that Preserves Insertion Order or .NET Implementation of LinkedHashSet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627085/HashSet-that-Preserves-Insertion-Order-or-NET)

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine a lot of custom implementation to have this kind of behavior, my question was more to know if there is an existing official collection that could make this.

Comment: I do not know any official implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `OrderedDictionary`, documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You will use your values from your current `List` as keys in the dictionary and you can leave value as some randomness.

```
OrderedDictionary myOrderedDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();
myOrderedDictionary.Add(1, "smth");
myOrderedDictionary.Add(2, "smth");

foreach (DictionaryEntry v in myOrderedDictionary)
{
    int youValue = (int)v.Key;
}
```

The only downfall here is that this dictionary doesn't use generics and you have to cast from `object` yourself.

Comment: Link in English: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: ew, not generic :(