# Time complexity of deletion in a linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why time complexity of link lists are O(1) according to [this website.](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) From what I understand if you want to delete an element surely you must traverse the list to find out where the element is located (if it even exists at all)? From what I understand shouldn't it be O(n) or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, you are not missing something.

If you want to delete a specific element, the time complexity is `O(n)` (where `n` is the number of elements) because you have to find the element first.

If you want to delete an element at a specific index `i`, the time complexity is `O(i)` because you have to follow the links from the beginning.

The time complexity of insertion is only `O(1)` if you already have a reference to the node you want to insert after. The time complexity for removal is only `O(1)` for a doubly-linked list if you already have a reference to the node you want to remove. Removal for a singly-linked list is only `O(1)` if you already have references to the node you want to remove and the one before. All this is in contrast to an array-based list where insertions and removal are `O(n)` because you have to shift elements along.

The advantage of using a linked list rather than a list based on an array is that you can efficiently insert or remove elements while iterating over it. This means for example that filtering a linked list is more efficient than filtering a list based on an array.

Comment: But say for Singly linked list you do have a reference to a pointer, for example we know the tail, wouldn't you still have to iterate through to list to find the previous node before the tail to update the current tail pointer?

Comment: Yes, that's true. You'd need a reference to the previous node too. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: What you say make sense, but surely it would be at least worst case would be O(n) over O(1)

Comment: Are you talking about removal or insertion?

Comment: Removal. Correct me if I'm wrong, at worst case we wouldn't know where the element is located?

Comment: When people say that removal for a singly linked list is `O(1)` what they mean is that you can break and create the links in constant time. Actually getting references to the node you want to remove (and to the one before) comes under `access` or `search` on that table (depending on whether you are doing it by index or looking for a specific value).

Comment: It is clear from your comments that you understand exactly how a linked list works and what the time-complexity of all the operations are. I think the debate is about the precise meaning of the word `remove`. What it means depends on what you already know.

Answer (score 3):

Your are correct.

Deletion:

1.If pointer is given in this case Time Complexity is O(1).

2.You **DON'T** have pointer to the node to be deleted(Search and Delete).
In this case Time Complexity is O(n).

Comment: I might be wrong, but for your first point, you would need a pointer to the node before the one you're deleting, not the one you're deleting.

Comment: You need a pointer to the node you want to delete but you only have it from the previous  node, so if you have a linked list A -> B -> C -> D and you want to delete node C, you will have a pointer to it from node B, then you reassign next value of pointer B to node D, thus excluding node C from the linked list. Node C is no longer referenced anywhere in a singly linked node list. In a doubly linked node list you would also have to reassign node D prev pointer to node B.