# Get index of a specified element in hashset C#

Tags: c#, indexing, element, hashset

I would like to know if there is a method to get the index of a specified element using hashsets.
For example,I have this condition,and I want to get the index of the specified element

```
    if(hash_set.Contains(search))
     {
       //Get index of element search
     }
```

Edit: Thanks for all your answers. I decided to use Dictionary<> instead!

Comment: No. A hashset doesn't have ordering, so trying to find a specific index doesn't make sense.

Comment: @sstan is there another container as fast as hashsets(for the contain function) that has ordering?

Comment: Try here: [HashSet that preserves ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552225/hashset-that-preserves-ordering)

Comment: Nope use a dictionary

Comment: The closest thing you can get is the key.

Comment: As sstan says, there's no such thing as the index of an element in a `HashSet<T>`, because that collection type is unordered. You will need a different collection type, i.e. as shown in the marked duplicate.