# How to sort the coordinates of a hash set in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, hashset

[image]

I'm saving coordinate values in the HashSet.

And I want to sort it in order in the picture above.

Below is a typical point structure, using a Hashset.

```
struct Point
{
    public int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

private HashSet<Point> hashset = new HashSet<Point>();
```

I found a source that just sort one value.

However, i have not found a source that sort two or coordinates values.

Give me an example of how to sort the coordinates.

Comment: How do you want points within a given quadrant to be ordered?

Comment: HashSets have no order, which means it doesn't matter whether you use a HashSet or an array to store the values. Do you want to *store* the values in a specific sort order (in which case you'll have to use a different container) or read them in a specific order? In that case you could use LINQ and any container that allows sorting with `Comparer` argument, and use a custom comparer

Comment: and for a set that conserve order https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552225/hashset-that-preserves-ordering

Comment: Actually HashSet does have an order since you can use it as IEnumerable and it does maintain order in reality, but it's not a behaviour that one can depend on since it's not guaranteed and of course it's not a good idea anyway to do that :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik But is unlikely to be insertion order and will possibly be completely different after adding an item.

Comment: I think it actually is, at least looked like that in my examples, but it's of course just a curiosity not a call to action :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom comparer to achieve what you want, where you can define your own rules:

```
var comparer = Comparer<Point>.Create((p1, p2) =>
{
    if (p1.y < p2.y)
    {
       return p1.x > p2.x ? 1 : -1;
    } 
    else
    {
       return p1.x < p2.x ? 1 : -1;
    }
});

hashset.OrderBy(p => p, comparer)
```

P.S. Not 100% sure that all the conditions are correct, but you get the idea I hope, so that you can write the logic you want following this example.

Answer (score 1):

```
points.OrderBy(p => Math.Atan2(p.y, p.x))
```

should do the trick.

It will order the points by their direction, measured from origin (i.e. starting from "west" in a clockwise direction)

If you're hoping to maintain that order in a set based structure, you'll need to think again because `HashSet<T>` has no implicit ordering.