# Is there any default order in which where clause in LINQ query filters sequence

Tags: c#, linq

```
public IQueryable<CarVersion> GetCar(int carIdToSearch)
{
    return _Dbcontext.CarVersion.Include("CarFactory").
            .Where(x => x.carId== carIdToSearch);
}
```

I have `CarVersion` table, which has two columns **version and carId**. Version column is primary key. There can be multiple version for single carId. `CarFactory` table has foreign key version from carVersion table. So I'm trying to understand, when I execute above query will it always give me results which are ordered in ascending  order. Or will it be based on  primary key? Or it can be guaranteed? I looked at MS documentation but it does not say anything about ordering.

Comment: There is no guarantee that order will be preserved. It may or may not be depending on provider. You can use LINQ `.OrderBy()` method if you need that order.

Answer (score 5):

The result you will get depends on the LINQ-provider. If it's Linq-To-Objects the order is stable(read below). It means it will be the same as it was in the source sequence. If it's a database driven LINQ provider like `Linq-To-Entities` the order  is not predetermined.

You need an `ORDER BY` in sql to ensure a certain order. So you need an `OrderBy` in LINQ:

```
return _Dbcontext.CarVersion.Include("CarFactory").
    .Where(x => x.carId== carIdToSearch)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Version);
```

- However, even in Linq-To-Objects it's not guaranteed that the order will always be the same. It also depends on the type of the sequence. Set based collections like a `Dictionary` or `HashSet` also don't guarantee that the order  stays the same as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384710/why-is-a-dictionary-not-ordered) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657263/does-hashset-preserve-insertion-order).