# Count of union two HashSet

Tags: c#, .net

There are two HashSet sequences. I need to count the result of union.
It should look like this:

```
    sequence1.UnionWith(sequence2);
    return sequence1.Count;
```

But I need to ensure that the original sequences do not change.
I used a simple search, but it very slows down the program

```
    var newHashkSet = new HashSet<string>(sequence1);
    foreach (var s2 in sequence2.Where(s2 => newHashkSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x == s2) == null)) {
        newHashkSet.Add(s2);
    }
    return newHashkSet.Count();
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: What do you mean by _"the original sequences do not change"_? Hashsets are unordered by definition. See also [Does HashSet preserve insertion order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657263/does-hashset-preserve-insertion-order).

Comment: I mean that after using   sequence1.UnionWith(sequence2) sequence1 is changing

Answer (score 4):

Use an `ImmutableHashSet`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467171(v=vs.111).aspx

By definition, immutable hash sets do not change. When you form the union of two immutable hash sets, the result is a *third* immutable hash set, not the mutation of either of the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick but not memory efficient way is that You can create a copy of hashSet and then do the union

```
var newset = new HashSet<string>(sequence1);
newset.UnionWith(sequence2);
netset.count
```