# Is the Linq extension First required to consistently return the same element on subsequent calls upon a HashSet?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know `HashSets` are inherently unordered, but of course the collection is stored in some order, probably based on the hash buckets. The `First` extension method grabs the first element and delivers it to the caller. My question is the following: since the .NET platform is a standard with potentially several implementations, is it written in stone that the `First` extension method (from the `System.Linq` namespace) should always return the same element for unordered collections like `HashSets` as long as that the contents of the collection don't change? I'm imagining things like memory optimisation moving instances around and maybe, if that was not one of the requirements of the standard for `First`, that could end up causing different behaviour on different implementations of the platform.

'Can I rely on `First` to behave, both now and in the future, no matter on what device?' would be the gist of what I'm asking.

Comment: Unless you cache a .First() on a HashSet today on a Win10 and compare it to a .First() on Android 12.3 in 15 years - for the same exact HashSet - you wont ever know. Just hope the HashSet implementation is the same then.

Comment: This answer explains that it would be a very bad idea to rely on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/657289/2651069

Comment: I'm interested why would you ever need to rely on this?

Comment: My solution to a problem that's not that simple to explain... basically a little part of a spell checker that uses no artificial intelligence whatsoever. A dumb spell checker. It's for my mum, an addon for her to use in her work software, because if she types something a little different, say an í instead of an i, she's in trouble. That's a little part of the solution. A tiny algorithm that would fit to do a tiny task inside the whole thing.

Comment: Maybe you need `SortedSet` instead (same as hash set but sorted). At least on it it makes sense to call First (unlike doing that on HashSet).

Comment: That could work. I don't exactly need the order of the elements among themselves, but I doubt it would break anything if that's what I got. And it would be a little price to pay compared to `List.Contains` on every insertion. Thank you for that advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on `First()` to return the first element returned by the `GetEnumerator()` call on the class you did `First()` on.

However, as with any unordered collection, it undefined behavior that the first item returned from `HashSet.GetEnumerator()` will always be the same item on multiple calls to a unchanged collection. It may return the same today, but there is no contract stating it needs to remain that way in future versions.

Comment: I understand. That's a shame... My whole algorithm just crumbled... I'll have to use a list and Contains instead I suppose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check: 
* creating multiple HashSet
* using First() on each insert of number into HashSet and remember each into another HashSet
* after all inserts all the HashSet contain the same data

Printing all First()'s

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<int> Range(int min, int max)
    {
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            yield return i;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var firsts = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Run: " + i.ToString());
            var h = new HashSet<int>();
            foreach (var num in Range(-1000, +1000).OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList())
            {
                h.Add(num);
                if (h.Count == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("first value inserted: " + num.ToString());
                firsts.Add(h.First());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("All firsts: " + string.Join(",", firsts));
            firsts.Clear();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Observations:

- each HashSet in itself produces only 1 First-Value over all 2001 inserts
- all HashSet produce different .First() - Values if they started with other first int

`Run: 0
    first value inserted: 507
    All firsts: 507
    Run: 1
    first value inserted: 511
    All firsts: 511
    Run: 2
    first value inserted: -600
    All firsts: -600
    Run: 3
    first value inserted: -624
    All firsts: -624
    Run: 4
    first value inserted: -367
    All firsts: -367
    Run: 5
    first value inserted: -110
    All firsts: -110
    Run: 6
    first value inserted: 983
    All firsts: 983
    ... etc ...`

- an HashSet instance seems to have the same First() in its livetime
- it is the first item put into the HashSet
- different HashSet filled differently seem to have different First()s when/if the first value differs
- At least under Windows and current compiler it seems for HashSet .First() it is predictable

Comment: Yes a `HashSet` seems to have the same return for `First` in my machine over the course of a little more than 40 minutes of testing. But my problem is knowing if that's a contract in the standard of .NET. Like, in the standard, long integers have to have 64 bits. You know that for sure, no matter which platform, no matter when (unless a breaking change is made to the standard) long ints will have 64 bits.