# Does HashSet preserve insertion order *if no items are deleted*

Tags: c#, .net, hashset

I know there have been several questions regarding `HashSet` and order preserving and very simple tests show that if adding and removing items the order will not be preserved at all.

But my question is explicitly related to whether insertion order is preserved if no items are ever deleted from the `HashSet`.

Back in 2009 Jon Skeet (https://stackoverflow.com/a/657289/10894153) said that:

> It's possible that if you never remove any items, it will preserve insertion order. I'm not sure, but I wouldn't be entirely surprised.

He reasoned at the time that:

> I haven't looked at the internal structures or source code (which I don't have, obviously).

Clearly this has changed and with .NET now being open sourced, I'm wondering if anyone can validate with certainty whether insert order is indeed preserved on a `HashSet` when no items are deleted.

Prior to asking this question I have performed a couple of *quick* tests with adding 1000 items to a `HashSet` and insertion order was preserved, but this is by no means proof that it will always be the case even if no deletions occur.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by HimBromBeere, official documentation for the `HashSet` states that order is not preserved and therefore even if current implementations maintain (although it is clear that they do **not** guarantee it) insertion order  this may change in the future.

That being said, I am interested in whether insertion order is maintained when no deletions occur *in the current implementation* (.NET 4.7.2)

Comment: You should simply **never** rely on that order, it´s an implementation-detail that is in no way guranteed to stay the same for all future versions.

Comment: See the [source-code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs) and proof yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/OndrejPetrzilka/Rock.Collections may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That being said, I am interested in whether insertion order is
>   maintained when no deletions occur in the current implementation.

Yes, it is maintained in 4.7.2. As of 18 Jan 2019.

I suspect part of the issue here is understanding the difference between contract and implementation.

The *implementation* of `HashSet` in 4.7.2 will maintain insertion order (if you don't remove items). But you didn't originally ask that. You asked whether:

> insertion order is guaranteed

And for that question, the answer is unequivocally No. A method's **guarantees** are not defined by the implementation, but by the contract. And the [contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) states:

> A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose
>   elements are in no particular order.

There is simply no way to read that statement in **any other way** than that there are **no** guarantees as to order.

*Now - you can choose to ignore the guarantees, and deploy an app relying on the current behaviour. And, as long as Microsoft doesn't release a Windows Update patch that changes the behaviour (or your code runs in a different implementation like Mono etc), you will probably be OK. But **probably** is not the same as **definitely** (or **guaranteed**).*

Comment: Updated question to replace guarantee with maintain.

Comment: Regardless, the thrust of my argument remains. Microsoft is 100% in their rights to release a patch which changes this behaviour tomorrow.