# An Ordered Data-Structure for 'Contains' and 'Iteration' in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I require a data structure that is dynamic (Add/Remove)
and that is the most efficient for

- `Contains()`
- `Iteration`

Both actions are called more often than (add/remove)

What about a combination from a List and a HashSet?

Comment: Sounds like you want a HashSet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You probably need [redis](https://redis.io/), rather than rolling your own cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @Ross Gurbutt the [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) satisfies your requirements. It does not, however, maintain the order of items inserted into it (or more precisely, it *might* not. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/657289/10657522) answer by Jon Skeet).

If the fidelity of the order is important to you, then the [SortedSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.8) might be what you're looking for.

Edit: The above recommendations go on the assumption that you do not want to allow for duplicates in your collection(s).

Also, as @Ross Gurbutt kindly pointed out (and as I should have mentioned originally):

> SortedSet.Contains is O(log n) whereas HashSet.Contains is O(1)

Comment: Agree, although it should be noted that SortedSet<T>.Contains is O(log n) whereas HashSet<T>.Contains is O(1). As @Heretic Monkey says above. It depends on which areas you care about the most and what your exact needs are

Comment: Contains in O(1) is quite important .. I think the HashSet is what I need. I will do some testing and pbbly mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one data structure.

#### Contains

Use a `HashSet` to get an O(1) access time to any element.

#### Find and Iteration

Use a `List<>` to add/remove items by index or to the end of the list: O(1).

That `List` can also be searched by a binary search if it's ordered: O(log(n)). If it is not ordered, that search is linear, O(n).

Iteration is iteration: always O(n)... in this case over your `List`.

Comment: Adding to a `List<T>` is only O(1) if the number of elements in it is smaller than its `Capacity`. Otherwise, it is an O(n) operation, where n is the `Count`. Removing from a `List<T>` by index is not O(1) but is, in fact, O(n), where n is (Count - index) as can be read in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

Comment: @DarrenRuane that's not what I meant. I'll fix it.

Comment: I got the feeling that iterating over a dictionary or a set is slower than over a list. Is there really no difference?